# Getting Allegro5 to build on Win7 with MinGW (cannot compile TTF)

Tags: compiler-errors, truetype, allegro5

## System & Environment

- Windows 7 (64 bit)
- MinGW 4.6.1
- Eclipse Indigo (Not really used in the build process)
- Windows PowerShell (Run as administrator)

## Summary of Issue

I am attempting to build Allegro5 in the environment above. This initially worked, and I was able to link to allegro and allegro-image and there were no issues. However when I tried to link to allegro-ttf it wasn't detected.

I went back to my logs and freetype wasn't found and so ttf support was dropped; oops! I got freetype and went about rebuilding Allegro5.

I won't copy the full build messages, but in a fresh build directory:

```
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
...stuff
Found Freetype: C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib/libfreetype.dll.a
...stuff
```

Looking good. Let's compile!

```
C:\Program Files\MinGW\allegro\build> mingw32-make -j4
...stuff
Scanning dependencies of target allegro_acodec
[ 24%] Building C object addons/acodec/CMakeFiles/allegro_acodec.dir/acodec.c.obj
[ 24%] Building C object addons/acodec/CMakeFiles/allegro_acodec.dir/wav.c.obj
Linking C shared library ..\..\lib\allegro_acodec-5.0.dll
Creating library file: ..\..\lib\liballegro_acodec.dll.a
[ 24%] Built target allegro_acodec
Scanning dependencies of target allegro_ttf
"C:/Program: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x004132f6)
mingw32-make[1]: *** [addons/ttf/CMakeFiles/allegro_ttf.dir/all] Error 255
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

## Other Details

I could just make my life easier and get the prebuilt binaries, but this is mainly an educational en-devour. One that has stumped me for an embarrassing amount of time.

I installed freetype2 which is now detected. So ttf is included in the build process. I'm not sure if freetype2 is to blame or not. I made sure to get the dev files, but compiling fails. I then tried building freetype2 myself, but it didn't change anything, same issue.

I'm not sure what the problem is. 0x5 is an access violation I believe? Maybe it has to do with the fact that "Program Files" has a space in it, and in the error we see "C:/Program"? I'm not supplying the paths directly, they are in my path variables. I tried wrapping my paths in quotes, but that cause them to not work at all. Maybe there is another method?

I'm a fish out of water here. I'd appreciate any help. Please comment if you require more details on my setup!

Thanks for your time <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have c:\allegro\build (where you are running cmake from), then I would create c:\allegro\build\deps\lib c:\allegro\build\deps\include and put the files (e.g., freetype, etc) in there. Allegro will automatically scan those locations.

Comment: After moving freetype to ..\build\deps\lib and ..\build\deps\include it built/compiled with no issues. Thanks a lot!